# Mobile Services are missing in the new Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have two running mobile services that have been created with the current portal at [manage.windowsazure.com](http://manage.windowsazure.com). I'm currently testing the new version at [portal.azure.com](http://portal.azure.com) and I found out that my mobile services (which are now presumably called *mobile apps*) are missing, along with their notification hub. Other services, like SQL servers, databases and web apps are all there though.

How can I manage my mobile services in the new portal?

Comment: I am also waiting for this to exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now, you can't manage you Mobile Services from the new portal.  You may also have noticed that you can't create a Node backend in the new portal.  These features will be added in the future.